# Error by using eval in function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, eval

I have the following MATLAB function:

```
function getDBLfileL1(pathInput,Name_file,folderName)
   DBL_files=dir([pathInput,'/*.DBL']); %get DBL files 
   fprintf('Reading DBL files ... ')
   for i = 1:length(DBL_files) %loop through all DBL files
       [HDR, CS]=Cryo_L1b_read([pathInput,'/',DBL_files(i).name]); %read data with ESA's Cryo_L1_read function
       Coord{i}.LAT_20Hz=CS.GEO.LAT; %store values to struct
       Coord{i}.LON_20Hz=CS.GEO.LON; 
       Coord{i}.BoundingBox_StartLATLON_StopLATLON=[HDR.START_LAT*10^-6,HDR.START_LONG*10^-6,HDR.STOP_LAT*10^-6,HDR.STOP_LONG*10^-6];
       Coord{i}.FileName=[pathInput,'/',DBL_files(i).name];
   end
   eval([Name_file '= Coord;']);
   save(['output/',folderName,'/',Name_file,'.mat'],Name_file,'-v7.3')
   fprintf('done\n')
end
```

And it is called in the following:

```
getDBLfileL1(pathInput,[folderNames{i},'_',folderNames1{j}],folderNames{i}); %read Data from DBL file
```

The Value of `Name_file` is `'2011_01'`, and I get the following error:

```
eval([Name_file])
Error: Invalid text character. Check for unsupported symbol, invisible character, or pasting of non-ASCII characters.
```

Does anyone know why this error occur or how I can change the file, that I can replace the `eval()` function?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You can use `matlab.lang.makeValidName( str )` to make `str` into a valid string for variables / m file names / column headings etc. However, the real solution is usually to not use `eval` wherever possible (basically anywhere) and just save your `Coord` variable into the file instead. How is any other code supposed to use an unknown variable name anyway?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast reply! I just let the code run with your tip `matlab.lang.makeValidName(str)` but now this error occur `'2011_01' is not a valid variable name.` I just applied `matlab.lang.makeValidName()` to this line also and let it run again (it need aprox. 60 min to reach that point in the code)

Comment: Strings starting with numbers aren't valid variable names, the `matlab.lang.makeValidName` function will add an `'x'` in front of the string to make it valid. Again, this is not the ideal solution. Why not just save the variable with the name `Coord` instead of some name which you'll have to interpret later?

Comment: It is a bit complicated, the name of the variable is at the same time the name of the text file which will be created later in the main code. This refers to the satellite measurement mode and time stamp, but I will now to save it in Coord and save it later with the other name, thanks a lot!

Comment: You'd be better off saving a struct (or other variable), with a field to specify this name and time stamp, as well as the `Coord` data, instead of trying to contain that information in the variable name itself. This would be better coding practise and more maintainable. My 2c done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right, you are trying to evaluate '2011_01= Coord;' , which means that you are assigning Coord into a variable called 2011_01, and variable names cannot start with numbers

Comment: It was my mistake, thanks! I thought I let the code run with a previous dataset but there the file structure was different so that I had a letter at the beginning, so it was  `SIR_LRM_L2_2011_01`